# BCryptPasswordEncoder definition in SpringBoot 2.0.2.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, encoder

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.
I have this config file defined.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Value("${jwt.route.authentication.path}")
    private String authenticationPath;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderBean());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
            .csrf().disable()

            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

            // don't create session
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()

            // Un-secure H2 Database
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter 
                            = new JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter(userDetailsService(), jwtTokenUtil, tokenHeader);

        httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  // required to set for H2 else H2 Console will be blank.
            .cacheControl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // AuthenticationTokenFilter will ignore the below paths
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.POST,
                authenticationPath
            )

            // allow anonymous resource requests
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
                "/",
                "/*.html",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/**/*.html",
                "/**/*.css",
                "/**/*.js"
            )

            // Un-secure H2 Database (for testing purposes, H2 console shouldn't be unprotected in production)
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**");
    }
}
```

But when I start the app. using Eclipse IDE I got this error in the console:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field passwordEncoder in com.bonanza.backend.service.UserService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
```

Even the bean is clearly defined in the config file..

I also tried using this other definiton with the same resut

```
@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean() {

            String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
        // This is the ID we use for encoding.
        String currentId = "pbkdf2.2018";

        // List of all encoders we support. Old ones still need to be here for rolling updates
        Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        //encoders.put(currentId, new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder(PBKDF2_2018_SECRET, PBKDF2_2018_ITERATIONS, PBKDF2_2018_HASH_WIDTH));
        encoders.put(currentId, new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder());

        //return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoders);
        return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoders);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Autowiring  PassswordEncoder in your **com.bonanza.backend.service.UserService** 
may be solves the issue.

```
 @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
```

**Edited**

In your config file First add

```
@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(jwtuserDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoderBean());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
```

and then replace `auth.passwordencode(passwordencodebean())` to  `auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());`in **configureGlobal()** method

Try it..this will work sure.

Comment: same result :-(

Comment: i have edited code in above answer..have you tried ?

Comment: The method authenticationProvider(DaoAuthenticationProvider) is undefined for the type 
 DaoAuthenticationConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder,JwtUserDetailsService>

Comment: check this example..it works fine for me..http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-password-encoder-bcrypt-example-with-hibernate/